# What are those devices sitting on top of instrument panel in this Baron?

Tags: feature-identification, angle-of-attack

On this Baron YT video:

what are the two devices sitting on top of the instruments panel, on both sides of the compass?

[image: YT screenshot]

I though at first it is some kind of HUD ([Head-Up Display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-up_display)), but it looks way too small, compared to, for example, [this Garmin device](https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/151152).

I tried to zoom in to see the marking on the left one but no success.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It’s a STC head up display angle of attack kit.  In addition to an angle of attack sensor being installed on the exterior of the aircraft, this device provides eye-level display of an angle of attack indicator. They’re becoming increasingly popular in general aviation airplanes and provides an additional sense of angle of attack, especially during low speed maneuvers.

You can see a similar STC part here

https://sarasotaavionics.com/avionics/valkyrie-hud-kit

Comment: Oh my god the product in the link! Talk about confusing and counterintuitive symbology!!!

Comment: I’m not sure why you would call it confusing per se. It displays the same info as any other angle of attack indicator.

Comment: @Jpe61 "counterintuitive" ? Could you elaborate on what you mean exactly?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do you have some insight on what sensor this uses? Because airliners AOA use some [specific sensor](https://www.claimsjournal.com/app/uploads/2019/03/users_iqjWHBFdfxIU_iCBELMV0mnyQ_v0_piFq5T3pJF0qzS8rF9LjsWaQ_-1x-1-580x432.png), while this one doesnt seem to need this.

Comment: Wedges, triagles, a split ball, a line. Designers of this system forgot the KISS principle.  I have a hunch I've seen this symbology in a military HUD somewhere, not sure. If it in fact is copied from a military system, it is still unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Let me add: a very good addon in principle, I just think that in a high load situation quickly reading that correctly might prove difficult.

Comment: @Jpe61 Other than the see-thru nature of it, this looks very much like the AoA indexer I remember from the T-38. Having flown with it for a while, it became quite familiar and intuitive to refer to in flight.

Comment: @Jpe61 Don't confuse violation of the KISS principle with your own lack of familiarity with the indications. It is a quite simple and intuitive display, inherited from military aircraft, when you have become acquainted with it. Most instruments in aircraft, even the best designed modern ones, can look counterintuitive to those unfamiliar.

Comment: If you think you can devise a simpler system than that used in actual production, and which sufficient professionals and experts would agree is simpler, you better get manufacturing fast because I don't think those experts and professionals will all be waiting for someone else to make it first.

Comment: The world is full of examples of solutions deemend simple, superior and whatnot by professionals and experts, which in actual use have proven to be confusing, even to fatal extents. Engineers at Nokia were convinced Symbian was the best and most intuitive UI. No, it was not.

Comment: @Jpe61 You are seeing the indicator with all of its sections illuminated. Many displays will form weird shapes and show confusing indications when all the sections are illuminated. In use, combinations of those segments are illuminated to produce things like colored arrows, a line, or a circle.

Comment: Just for the record, I was not assuming it looks like that all the time 

Answer (score 8):

This is an Angle Of Attack indicator, specifically Alpha Systems’ [Eagle Above Dash HUD Kit](https://www.alphasystemsaoa.com/index.php?id=542):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that link! The [operation](https://alphasystemsaoa.com/assets/PDFs/eagle/Eagle%20Operations%20Manual%20Rev%20BA%2002272017.pdf) and [installation](https://alphasystemsaoa.com/assets/PDFs/eagle/Eagle%20Installation%20Manual%20Rev%20BA%20030817.pdf) manuals give a good explanation on the principles (measuring the air pressure difference on two nearby locations, from what I understood).

Comment: Appropriate that they're mounted next to a little eagle statuette...